# Scrape values from a javascript tag depending on a variable inside

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping

I am writing a PHP script to get some javascript variables values (geographic coordinates) that can be found inside a single `<script>` tag,

```
<script>
....
myFirstVariableValue = 58.922;
mySecondVariableValue = -12.179;
....
myLastVariableValue = 45.425;
....
</script>
```

I don't like the idea to get the whole HTML (it's huge) and use a regular expression for each of my variables on the whole page content, so I was thinking to use xpath to find the right script tag (there are many and many of them) and then get the variables.

```
preg_match("myFirstVariableValue\ =\ (-?\d+.\d+)/",$HTML,$matches);
preg_match("mySecondVariableValue\ =\ (-?\d+.\d+)/",$HTML,$matches);
...
preg_match("myLastVariableValue\ =\ (-?\d+.\d+)/",$HTML,$matches);
```

So, I would like to find with an xpath query the right script tag, and then run the regular expressions on the script tag content only.

The problem is the xpath query: is it even possible to do something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a ton of attempts, I finally was able to find the right query, and it's even pretty simple.

First I get the right script using **contains** on the script text content

```
$script = $xpath->query("//script/text()[contains(.,'myFirstVariableValue')]");
```

After that, I can use the `$script` variable to limit the scope of the regular expressions

```
preg_match("myFirstVariableValue\ =\ (-?\d+.\d+)/",$script->item(0)->textContent,$matches);
preg_match("mySecondVariableValue\ =\ (-?\d+.\d+)/",$script->item(0)->textContent,$matches);
...
preg_match("myLastVariableValue\ =\ (-?\d+.\d+)/",$script->item(0)->textContent,$matches);
```